# Ajax is not working with remote server in VPN

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, remote-access

I am trying to access a json file from a remote server using Ajax and plot and then trying to plot the graph using jqplot.

I doubt that my Ajax is not working with the remote server. the same url I can access from my browser but Ajax is not working with the same. Below is my code....Can anyone please highlight the mistake I am making:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.jqplot.css" />

<script src="jqplot.canvasTextRenderer.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jqplot.canvasAxisLabelRenderer.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.jqplot.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jqplot.dateAxisRenderer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="jqplot.ohlcRenderer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jqplot.highlighter.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jqplot.cursor.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jqplot.pointLabels.min.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

$.ajax({
  url: "http://172.xx.xxx.xxx/mc_measurement_new1.json",
  type: "GET"
  dataType: "jsonp",
  crossDomain:true,
  contentType:'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  success: function (data) {
    populateGraph(data);
  }
});


function populateGraph(ret) {
    var line1 = [];

    for (i = 0; i < ret.length; i++) {
      // Save the data to the relevant array. Note how date at the zeroth position (i.e. x-axis) is common for both demand and supply arrays.
      line1.push([ret[i].id, ret[i].res]);
    }

    var plot2 = $.jqplot('chart1', [line1], {  
      series:[{showMarker:false}],
      axes:{
        xaxis:{
          label:'ID',
          labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer
        },
        yaxis:{
          label:'Delay',
          labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer
        }
      }
  });
  };
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="chart1" style="height: 400px; width: 600px;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any error in the js console?

Comment: No, I am not getting any error in the console, it just like when I run this code in eclipse via browser.........i am getting a blank browser........

Comment: By the way, does my code look fine to you?

Comment: If it's blank how are you sure the page is even loading?

Comment: when I use the data of my json file directly into the code without Ajax, I am getting the plot with the same code.....but when I comment out my data and use Ajax with url of json file, it does not work........

Comment: Is the host for the Ajax request the same as the page it is called from (same name, or in this case, same IP address)? Is the protocol the same? Add an error callback and log what's returned there. Add a log in you success callback.

Comment: I am running this script from eclipse on my laptop and the json file is kept at a remote server on my university's internal network. I am connected to that server via VPN and I tried to fetch that JSON file using the same url on the browser and it works but when I try accessing it from my code in eclipse it doesnt work and there is no error message either

Answer (score 0):

When you use `jsonp` as the datatype, you must provide a callback, you don't have to use the success option.

Check out the jQuery api docs: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Look for `jsonp` and `jsonpCallback` options.